# How can I flush stdout for a process under nohup?

Tags: nohup

Is there a way to flush the buffer that nohup buffers stdout? From what I read in various places ([eg. some place](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/848547-print-statements-not-sent-nohup-out)) is that I can modify the behaviour from within my programm. But that would be specific to each programm, and there are some where I would not want to mess with the code.

So I am looking for a general way to tell a 'nohuped' programm to flush stdout. Something on the commandline like`flush sdtout <PID>`. Is there something like that? Or some sort of workaround?

~

Comment: What kind of output does your program generate? (Line oriented with trailing newline?) What OS and programming language do you use?

Comment: Line oriented with trailing newline. OS Linux, programming langue varies: bash, perl, python ... I was looking for something independent of the used language, but maybe I am on the wrong track there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible the ([deceptively simple](http://expect.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/expect/expect/example/unbuffer?view=markup&pathrev=HEAD)) [`unbuffer`](http://expect.sourceforge.net/example/unbuffer.man.html) script that comes with [`expect`](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) may do what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you, that is pretty much what I was looking for. Very helpfull!

Comment: So, would it be like `nohup unbuffer script.sh &`?

Comment: It should be `nohup unbuffer sh script.sh &`. For more details have a look at the comments in OP's question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28235928/telling-nohup-to-write-output-in-real-time